# How did Sebastian Shaw/Dr. Schmidt become a mutant and have powers in "X-Men: First Class"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

In *X-Men: First Class*, in Nazi Germany, Dr. Schmidt is a human.  Later, during the Cuban missile crisis, when he goes by Sebastian Shaw, he is a mutant with powers. How did he become a mutant?

Comment: What specifically makes you think he wasn't a mutant in Nazi Germany?

Comment: Mutants are born not made.

Comment: @Jontia - Ahem; https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/Mutant_Growth_Hormone

Comment: @Valorum "Non-mutants become [mutates](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/Mutate)"

Comment: @Jontia - Potato potato

Comment: Really weird question TBH, why aren't you asking the same of any of the other mutants in the movie?

Answer (score 7):

I don't see why you'd think Shaw was a mere human in Nazi Germany. Sure, he might not have made a show of his powers, but nothing indicates he was human; in fact, there are two scenes that very much indicate the contrary.

The first is when Shaw absorbs a grenade.

> I've got the power to absorb energy. Keeps me young.

Presumably he has been doing this for some time. Even before the 40s, probably.

The second is a combination of what he explains to young Erik in the beginning, about evolution and a new age in the human reign, and the dialogue in the final confrontation, when Magneto explains how Shaw was unlocking his powers. This very much indicates that Shaw was a mutant all along, IMO.